# Integrate C and JAVA in Blackberry

Tags: java, c, blackberry, java-native-interface

What is the best way to integrate C with JAVA for Blackberry app?

In core java, we can use JNI for integration. But in Blackberry app ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have some potential solutions for this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764389/porting-c-library-to-java-for-blackberry-application/7403930#7403930

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't integrate C, as RIM does not expose any API for the platform. Since BlackBerry use a j2me-compliant JVM, JNI is not exposed.

Prior answer is partially correct - you may write code that uses only the J2ME API, but you can also use RIM's own Java API for better/more advanced features and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There's no equivalent to JNI for BlackBerry apps.  Everything must be written in j2me. 
I suggest you ask a new StackOverflow question about whatever it is you are trying to accomplish with C code in your BlackBerry app.