# Porting C library to Java for Blackberry application

Tags: c, blackberry, java-me, jna, porting

I need to port a C library to Java so it can run on the Blackberry platform (mobile, native application). The options I am considering are:

1. bytecode conversion (cibyl, etc)
2. Complete port
3. Wrap C code around Java using JNA (would this even work for Blackberry?)

Please let me know which option is best. thanks

Comment: How big is this library? Did you write it yourself? JNI/JNA are somewhat tricky to use. However, if the code is not your own, or there is a lot of it, it might be the best way to go. Really, it's situation dependent.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. The library is not huge, and I did not write it myself (it is open source). It is about 30-40 .c files.

Comment: Have you used JNA before and do you know if it will work?

Comment: Off topic, but what does the library do? Perhaps there's a Java equivalent someone could suggest?

Comment: porting C to java is quite a straightforward process. sit your butt and port it.

Comment: Have not used JNA before. No there is not an equivalent Java version, as the owner of that library only made it in C. And that is the specific library I need to use for this project (requirement), so cannot really look for "equivalents".

Comment: Isnt Blackberry JDE legacy? You might want to go with a full port.

Answer (score 3):

Aha. Some quick googling says "No, JNI does not work for blackberry" source:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Can-we-use-JNI-Java-Native-Interface-approach-in-Blackberry/m-p/365362

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/JNI/m-p/41140.

So you're stuck with bytecode conversion and complete port. Since I have no idea what bytecode conversion is, I'd go with a complete port, so long as you are familiar with both languages. If you can define bytecode conversion for me, I might be able to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

We also have an in-house developed C library for core functionality of our iOS and Android apps.

I asked about using cibyl to run this on BlackBerry in the form of a .jar and the good news is that it's possible: https://twitter.com/#!/simonkagstrom/status/114581622833152000 [backup of the tweet: "Sure, that's how #waze on the blackberry works."]

You can also try MoSync: http://twitter.com/#!/MoSync/status/115088826430533632 [backup of this one: "Yup, you can use MoSync for BB. There's "experimental" Blackberry support in MoSync 2.6, already used in live apps!"]

And David A Roberts, developer of LLJVM sent me this: "I'm not familiar with BlackBerry development, but I see no obvious reason why LLJVM wouldn't work, so long as the library doesn't rely too much on things like the C POSIX library (e.g. dirent.h, etc) - I
never got around to implementing this fully. Otherwise LLJVM would need to be updated suitably..."

Side note: BlackBerry's new Tablet OS and planned BBX phones actually have a native SDK but this QNX based stuff is [quite unpopular](http://www.digitimes.com/news/a20110920PD212.html). We just need to wait if BBX is going to become a success since Java based solutions are just too much risks.