# Using c++ classes in blackberry or convert cpp files to java

Tags: android, c++, blackberry, converters

I am having C++ files and library which I have used in Android using ndk and jni.It works fine in Android. But now I want to use the same files and library for Blackberry Development. I am trying to convert the cpp files in to java but there are large number of cpp files which is thus not a proper solution to try to convert around hundreds of files

I want to know are there any cpp to java converters available or how can I use the jni in my Blackberry application development.

Or are there any better options??

Comment: Java and C++ are two completely different languages. You can't just "convert" one to the other. Even a naive porting of the code is a very non-trivial operation, and if you want to do it in a sophisticated way (using the target language's idioms), this is a serious programming effort.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764389/porting-c-library-to-java-for-blackberry-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Blackberry smartphones do not support JNI at all, so using C++ is completely out of the question on those devices. You have to use Java only.

BlackBerry PlayBook v1.0.7+, and future OS7 smartphones, will have an NDK that supports C++.  Java will not be used on those devices (except in the Android player), so no JNI needed.

Comment: Can I then use this C++ libraries for iphone and windows mobile development.

Comment: not "future OS7 smartphones" but future BBX smartphones -- RIM trashes OS7 completely in favor of QNX