# C++ library for mobile application

Tags: android, iphone, c++, blackberry, mobile

I have my own C++ library with source code. It contains functions like this: CreateDvice, FillDevice, CloseDevice and etc. There is no dependency to any third-party libraries.
There is requirement to create application for mobile platform:

1. Blackberry
2. iPhone
3. Android

The application has to use logic provided by this library.
Is there chance to use existing library in mobile application or at least some of them?
Or does it require to re-implement library code for each platform?

Comment: for God's shake, they asked the exact same question one day before yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077007/using-c-classes-in-blackberry-or-convert-cpp-files-to-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS (iPhone/iPad) you can directly compile your library and use it from a regular iOS app written in Objective-C++ and/or C++.

For Android you can directly compile your library using the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), then either write your app in Java and call your library via JNI, or write the whole app in C++ using the NDK.

I believe you are out of luck on Blackberry, for this platform you'll need to rewrite your library in Java, as neither apps or libs can be written in C++.

**Edit**: See my other answer for a completely different approach that may work for you.

Comment: Does it make sense to convert current C++ library to Java library to have it used at all mobile platforms? Will Java library will be available everywhere?

Comment: You won't be able to use the java converted library everywhere. On iOS you'll use the C++ lib, on Blackberry you'll use the Java version, and on Android you can use either. Unfortunately you'll have to maintain both versions of the library.

Comment: @jkshneider: I hope you are not seriously suggesting that he converts his native C++ library to Java, then drop the original C++ code and instead cross-compile the converted Java lib back to Obj-C to use in iOS. That would be looking for a serious headache!

Comment: The problem seems like pretty general in mobile env. There are a lot of code implemented in C++ libraries, and it's pretty difficult to re-implement it for each platform. And the more headache to maintain a few versions of same logic. I hoped that there are some kind of general solution of this problem.

Comment: @Miguel: I am seriously suggesting porting the library.  This is the only way that he is guaranteed to use the same code base for all 3 platforms.  If a web service is feasible, that would be the preferred platform, but is obviously more expensive to maintain and suffers from scalability concerns.

Comment: Note that current Blackberry *smartphones* do not support C++ or an NDK at all, only Java, whereas the Blackberry *PlayBook* tablet does support C++ and an NDK.  Once Blackberry *smartphones* switch to the new QNX-based OS in the near future, and PlayBook is updated to match that OS, neither platform will support Java at all anymore (except for PlayBook's Android player), just a C++ NDK (ignoring WebWorks and Adobe AIR, which are separate development platforms).

Comment: @Miguel You might want to update your answer to reflect the fact that in the new Blackberry-10 OS the native language is C++.

Answer (score 1):

**Blackberry:**

It's technically possible to have ASM on BlackBerry (or Android, iPhone, etc.) but 3rd-party developers are often not allowed (or not able in the case of BlackBerry) to do so.

**iPhone:**

Absolutely.  You can statically link a C++ library.  Of course it will have to be compiled with the right instruction set.  There are a host of examples out there on how to do this.  Translate - you will need the code.

**Android:**

Absolutely.  There is a good book on this by Mark Murphy.  Introductory material here:
http://www.androidguys.com/2009/10/14/android-beyond-java-part-one/

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_choice/ndk.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Do you need a cross-platform library/engine to create a mobile application?

If it is so, Cocos2D would be the best choice. Originally it's a game engine, but it is suitable for applications too. And it supports all the platforms written above.

Comment: Let me clarify. There is C++ library with interface : CreateDevice, FillDevice, ClearDevice. I need to create application which uses these functions. The question is - can I somehow to use existing implementation in library instead of implementation CreateDevice, FillDevice, ClearDevice in each mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of compiling your C++ library on each target device that you intend to support, you could opt for creating a service that packs your library. You can install this library on a host you have control, then from each platform the only thing you need to do is invoke this service.

I'm not sure if this thing makes sense for the kind of library that you have, but this would be a way to maintain a single version of your library, and you'll have a guaranteed same behavior on all devices.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Android is not natively Java, it's natively C++. And iOS is also natively C++. So why not just leave the C++ code untouched and drop RIM's current platform (since they are switching to BBX which does support C++ as well).

Comment: Android is not native C++.  It supports C++ via Java JNI, but development for Android is still based on Java.

Comment: nope, you don't need to go through the Java JNI, look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

For Blackberry you can use the C++/Qt Cascades; for iOS you can use C/C++ & Objective-C (a superset of C) and Android can use the C++ NDK. You can use Java on all platforms as long as the Java apps are standalone and the JRE is pre-packaged with the app (iOS). You can interface with C/C++ libs using JNI

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a Java library on all platforms, that would work.

Android and Blackberry are natively Java.

You can use a tool called XMLVM to cross-compile your Java library to Objective C for use on iOS.

http://xmlvm.org/overview/

It is not 100% perfect, but pretty darn close.  We use it extensively to port common Java library code to iOS.  Port the C++ library to Java and you are good to go.